# Connecting EFTPOS machine to POS Java

Tags: java, tcp

We are trying to link the EFTPOS Machines at our stores to the POS, so as
staff do not have to enter the sale amount manually in the EFTPOS machine,
but is done automatically through the POS sale amount. Does anyone know a
way in which this can be done? Any help would be appreciated.

The EFTPOS machine providers gave a client software which communicates using TCP/IP. All i need to do is establish a connection to the tat port and send messages. But i am not sure how to do that ? If anyone has done this before throw some light on it plz..

----EDIT---

actually the EFTPOS machine is connected to a phone line to dial the bak(this part i am not worried about). Now i have to connect the EFTPOS to my computer using RS232 pin. I have a java application running on my machine and i need to talk to the EFTPOS machine from my application. The supplier of the machine said it is using TCP/IP protocol for communication. Now what are the steps i need to follow ?

Comment: I'm not even sure where this is on topic.  Possibly superuser, maybe serverfault.  It is not, however, on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each device has an RJ45 port (like on a telephone cord, but bigger), connect both devices to a router (for example, Linksys) with category 5 Ethernet cable, and run the software. The router should automatically assign IP numbers to each device and hopefully the software will have a means of scanning the network to locate the POS device. Without more info that's all I can think of.

---

TCP/IP over serial is possible of course, using SLIP or PPP. But I think you need to get more data from your vendor. See if you can get someone with some technical skills to talk to you, not a sales droid.